# Validate uniqueness of email/phone on Stripe checkout page

Tags: validation, stripe-payments, payment, checkout

After Customers checkout from Stripe payment link, We use their filled email and phone to create record/signup in our database on confirmation page. Our business requires that email and phone should be unique. Therefore when some customers enter duplicate detail (email/phone) it causes issues.

Is there a way that we can enforce email address and phone to be unique? Either through some Stripe web hook or configuration on Stripe end.

One way I know I can use is to create my own checkout session with pre-validated email/phone but I want to avoid that.

Comment: Stripe won't validate uniqueness of your customers' email address or phone. You'll need to perform this validation in your own application.

Comment: I was reading your reading your useful answer ans I'am trying to match with Stripe documentation. stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions Now we are sending only those: 1. client_reference_id 2. customer_email Reading your answer I see that we could use this: 1. customer string. Our team created and end point to validate if the user exists at Stripe, and we receive it if exists : { "id": "cus_NKMd1kkrBTtZk", ..... } For customer Should I send the id string that I receive from this end point?